# I cannot configure usb devices via xinput

Tags: ubuntu, input-device, xinput

I would like to have access to my input devices settings. In the previous versions of ubuntu I was used to do that via `xinput`.
However xinput provides the following input:

```
WARNING: running xinput against an Xwayland server. See the xinput man page for details.
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer:16                       id=6    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-relative-pointer:16              id=7    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer-gestures:16              id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ xwayland-keyboard:16                      id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

I have one mouse and 2 touchpads connected to my machine but I cannot see them. Even if I disconnect them from my machine the output of xinput is always the same.

In addition there is a sort of competition between Xwayland and xinput, in fact if I try to disable one device, e.g. the number 8 through the command `xinput disable 8` I obtain the following error:

```
WARNING: running xinput against an Xwayland server. See the xinput man page for details.
```

How can I visualize the connected devices in order to deal with them?

My ubuntu release is 22.04.

Comment: Having the same problem on a Thinkpad. Did you find out any insight to share?

Comment: @Kamafeather No I didn't; Xwayland also creates annoying messages when you use gnuplot